# Syntax error in an object which has an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why the code below is invalid. It gives the following error: `SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name`. If I remove the outer curly braces it works. But I am wondering why it wouldn't work with the curly braces.

```js
const example2 = {[
  {
    'title': 'Hello World',
    'Author': 'John Doe',
  },
  {
    'title': 'Hello World2',
    'Author': 'John Doe',
  },
]};

console.log(example2);
```

Comment: Because curly brackets means it’s an object.  Why would you need it? You want an array of objects: so start with `[`.

Comment: @Terry because This is the way I use it in a property of a react object.

Answer (score 0):

Objects have key/value pairs. Your example2 object had an array (value) with no key.

```js
const example2 = {"array" : [
  {
    'title': 'Hello World',
    'Author': 'John Doe'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Hello World2',
    'Author': 'John Doe'
  }
]};

console.log(example2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting an array inside an object, without defining the key (or the property).

Object is a key/value pair, you can't give a value without a key.

```
var myObj = {
  myArr: [{
      'title': 'Hello World',
      'Author': 'John Doe',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Hello World2',
      'Author': 'John Doe',
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name

Because **there is an error with the Object initializer syntax**.

An object can be created using the `“key: value”` pair.

And in your case, you have initialized **`example2` object without the key**.

```js
const example2 = {
  "key": [{
      'title': 'Hello World',
      'Author': 'John Doe',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Hello World2',
      'Author': 'John Doe',
    },
  ]
};

console.log(example2);
```